# HTML/CSS/JS Random Div Position without Overlap Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I am attempting to make a webpage that randomly positions divs across the page on loading without them overlapping. I found code online that does exactly what I want it to, ([Linked Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266019/randomly-place-divs-on-webpage-and-make-sure-they-dont-overlap)) but I am having issues with the code...

I copied all of the components from the above link into a pre-existing site, but it does not work. All of the divs appear to be overlapping in the top right corner of the page. A commenter said it worked for them, but I don't see why it wouldn't work on my computer.

I would appreciate any help in making this feature work, as I would love to use it on a website I am working on. Below is a photo of what the page looks like on load...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/daFUY.jpg

```js
;(() => {
  "use strict";
  const TRIES_PER_BOX = 50;
  const randUint = range => Math.random() * range | 0;
  const placing  = [...document.querySelectorAll(".random")].map(el => Bounds(el, 5));
  const fitted = [];
  const areaToFit = Bounds();
  var maxTries = TRIES_PER_BOX * placing.length;
  while (placing.length && maxTries > 0) {
      let i = 0;
      while (i < placing.length) {
          const box = placing[i];
          box.moveTo(randUint(areaToFit.w - box.w), randUint(areaToFit.h - box.h));
          if (fitted.every(placed => !placed.overlaps(box))) {
              fitted.push(placing.splice(i--, 1)[0].placeElement());
          } else { maxTries-- }
          i++;
      }
  } 
  function Bounds(el, pad = 0) {   
      const box = el?.getBoundingClientRect() ?? {
          left: 0, top: 0, 
          right: innerWidth, bottom: innerHeight, 
          width: innerWidth, height: innerHeight
      };
      return {
          l: box.left - pad, 
          t: box.top - pad, 
          r: box.right + pad, 
          b: box.bottom + pad,
          w: box.width + pad * 2,
          h: box.height + pad * 2,
          overlaps(bounds) { 
              return !(
                  this.l > bounds.r || 
                  this.r < bounds.l || 
                  this.t > bounds.b || 
                  this.b < bounds.t
              ); 
          },
          moveTo(x, y) {
              this.r = (this.l = x) + this.w;
              this.b = (this.t = y) + this.h;
              return this;
          },
          placeElement() {
              if (el) {
                  el.style.top = (this.t + pad) + "px";
                  el.style.left = (this.l + pad) + "px";
                  el.classList.add("placed");
              }
              return this;
          }
      };
  }
  })();
```

```css
.random {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: xx-large;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0pc;
  
}
.placed {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="random">Div 1</div>
    <div class="random">Div 2</div>
    <div class="random">Div 3</div>
    <div class="random">Div 4</div>
    <div class="random">Div 5</div>
    <div class="random">Div 6</div>
    <div class="random">Div 7</div>
    <div class="random">Div 8</div>
    <div class="random">Div 9</div>
    <div class="random">Div 10</div>
    <div class="random">Div 11</div>
    <div class="random">Div 12</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested the code you provided but it seems to work perfectly. Would you be able to provide the rest of the code from the place you copied it to and a screenshot of the output?

Comment: I copied my HTML, CSS, and JS files as they are in my website directory. Here is the output. Here is a photo of the page when opened. https://imgur.com/XiI6u7F

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, check your question, I added the code snippet

Comment: Yes - I see that it works, but it does not work when I open the HTML file on my desktop. A photo of the output is attached in the post. Let me know if you know why it might not be working. :)